# Azure terraform Use existing managed identity to authenticate web app

Tags: azure-devops, terraform-provider-azure

I hope somebody can help me to solve this issue.

Using terraform I scripted some resource groups and webapps. Those web app have some configurations that need to access a key vault to retrieve some secrets.
But to do so, I need to activate the azure identity on the web app.
So far everything is working just fine without any problem. But as I am still learning how to use terraform with azure, I need to keep destroying and spinning up the webapps, which mean everytime I need to activate the `identity` and add the `access policy` in the key vault.

So what I did, is to create a `azure managed identity` resource in the same resource group where I have the key vault. Now I would like to use this `managed identity` to authenticate my web app everytime I spin up the web app.

My web app code looks like this:

```
resource "azurerm_app_service" "app-hri-stg-eur-configurations-api" {
  name                = "app-hri-${var.env}-${var.reg-name}-webapp-testing"
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.ASP-hri-stg-eur-webapp.id
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg-hri-stg-eur-webapp.name
  app_settings = {
    "secret"        = "@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://mykeyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/test)"
    ...... <My configuration>
  }
  identity {
    type = "UserAssigned"
  }
}
```

And here is where I am getting confused, how can I reference the azure managed identity that I have already created to grant access to my web app to read the secrets?

I hope I made my question clear enough, and please if not just ask for more info

Thank you so much for any help you can provide

Answer (score 1):

[A identity block supports the following](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/app_service):

- type - (Required) Specifies the identity type of the App Service. Possible values are SystemAssigned (where Azure will generate a Service Principal for you), UserAssigned where you can specify the Service Principal IDs in the identity_ids field, and SystemAssigned, UserAssigned which assigns both a system managed identity as well as the specified user assigned identities.
- identity_ids - (Optional) Specifies a list of user managed identity ids to be assigned. Required if type is UserAssigned.

so you should have sth like [this](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/user_assigned_identity):

```
data "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "example" {
  name                = "name_of_user_assigned_identity"
  resource_group_name = "name_of_resource_group"
}
```

If your identity is in another resource group. It allows you to reference to already created azure resource.

```
  identity {
    type = "UserAssigned",
    identity_ids = [data.azurerm_user_assigned_identity.example.id]
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you reply. That solved my doubt. But even if the web app has the UserAssigned identity, and the key vault has the managed identity in the access policies. My web App cannot resolve the key vault reference. Do you have any idea why is this happening? managed identity has the permission to get, set and list the secrets.

Comment: It could depend how you try to reach you KeyVault. Please take look on [AzureDefaultCredentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/identity-readme#defaultazurecredential)